# Show *only* a toast (no UI) after sharing text into an app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I'm a starting Android developer and would like to know how to achieve this:

1# User is using e.g. Chrome
2# User wants to share the page (meaning: the URL, which is text) into an app
3# User chooses the app from the share menu
4# The app shows **only** a small notification **on top** of Chrome (current foreground app, which is the sender of the intent)

So the app would receive the intent from Chrome and do something with it, but wouldn't change the foreground app. It would stay in the background and show only a very small notification to the user that the sharing of the URL into this app actually succeeded. Toast or something like that.

This is basically the way for instance Pocket handles sharing into it.

How can I achieve this? IntentService? I cannot seem to find the correct answer to this. Theme.NoDisplay, Intent, IntentService – I cannot figure out the correct way since I'm not too familiar with Android yet.

Thank you a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use the NoDisplay theme (update activity declaration in manifest) in the activity that does your sharing work as follows:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
```

This will prevent the activity from being displayed.

Then once the activity starts, do your sharing task, display the Toast and call `finish()`

Answer (score 0):

finish your activity onResume(). It will not shows any of Your Activity.

You can do like this:

```
 protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        finish();
    }
```